# Assign Row Colors Dynamically to ListView WPF from SQL Database

Tags: c#, css, wpf, listview

I'm new to WPF and having trouble using the databinding templates. I've searched for hours and struggle to find a way to make this work.

I have a listview that populates from a sql server. Inside the list view, I want rows to change colors to match their appropriate statuses. I want to avoid assigning a color to the Lead Class, so I need to pull the colors from a SQL table and dynamically set them. The code below works with a button click and will probably work as a method, but apparently this isn't the "WPF way". How can I do this the "correct" way?

Note: Each Status and their respective color will always be different.

```
private void addLeadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable sqlColorList = SqlLoader.selectFromSqlDatabase("Select * FROM statusTable");

    int i = 0;
    foreach (Lead test in LeadListView.Items)
    {
        foreach (DataRow color in sqlColorList.Rows)
        {
            if (test.LeadStatus == color["status"].ToString())
            {
                ListViewItem row = LeadListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as ListViewItem;
                row.Background = (Brush)new System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter().ConvertFromString(color["color"].ToString());
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}


<ListView x:Name="LeadListView" Width="494" Margin="10,127,0,34"     HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" Width="121" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LeadFirstName}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" Width="121" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LeadLastName}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Status" Width="121" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LeadStatus}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Date" Width="121" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LeadDate, StringFormat='MM/dd/yyyy'}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing that in code. In your XAML just bind the Background property to the LeadStatus property and specify a value converter to convert it from a LeadStatus to a Brush.

Comment: Not sure how to make the match and convert in XAML

Example: 
Two Databases.. Db 1 = Statuses Db 2 = Leads
Lead A Status = "Credit Failed", no color assigned.
Need the status from Lead A from DB 1, to the Status and its color in Db2.

Comment: So in your XAML, you would do: {Binding Path=LeadStatus, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}. In your converter, WPF will pass in the LeadStatus, and then you would just do something like return GetBrushFromDB2(status). If they don't change, you can statically cache them in your converter for performance.